# Error while creating a disconnected ADO recordset

Tags: vb6, ado

I'm trying to create a disconnected recordset with ADO including a Memo field (adLongVarWChar).
For some reason it gets converted back to adVarWChar.
What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim rs As New Recordset

    rs.Fields.Append "test", adLongVarWChar, 512, adFldIsNullable Or adFldLong Or adFldMayBeNull Or adFldMayDefer Or adFldUnknownUpdatable
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Type & " <- This should be 203 (adLongVarWChar) but it returns 202 (adVarWChar)"

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `-1` instead of `512` for size.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, for some reason, you need to first add a record, then the DataType returns correctly:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim rs As New Recordset

    rs.Fields.Append "test", adLongVarWChar, &H7FFFFFFF, adFldIsNullable Or adFldLong Or adFldMayBeNull Or adFldMayDefer Or adFldUnknownUpdatable
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Type & " <- This should be 203 (adLongVarWChar) but it returns 202 (adVarWChar)"
    rs.Open
    rs.AddNew
    rs.Update
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Type & " <- This is now 203 (adLongVarWChar)"

    Unload Me
End Sub
```